# Entity Framework: What is use /Meaning of (?) question mark

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I am new to my project, in the project they used Entity Framework & LINQ to 
manipulate the DB data. Here I am not able to understand why the question mark (?) is used after get() method in the following query. Is it possible to use the (?) mark as like below ?. If yes, then could you please explain in detail.

```
 uOW.ApplicationDetailsRepository.Get()?
                    .Where (x=>x.Name=="SomeConditions").Tolist();
```

Comment: To be fair to the poor fellow, the way the code is written with the LINQ `.Where` appearing on the following line makes it hard to realise that the `?` is being used in conjunction with the `.`.   Makes it harder to Google

Comment: Thanks @Stephen Muecke for editing the question. I did't find the link while searching this question in stack-overflow, so only asked my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the question mark is used this way (in combination with the period: `?.`), it is called the Null-conditional operator. It is a check for `null` before attempting the rest of the statement.

Here is a [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) explaining in detail.

Comment: @MdAslam that usage is the ternary operator, [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator)

Comment: @MickyD You make a good point, I'll go ahead and update the answer with that clarification.

Comment: Thank-you for the update +1 :)